# How to show menu items of a menu, on mouse hover in javafx8

Tags: css, menu, javafx-8, menuitem, fxml

I have a menu with some menu items. I would like to show the menu items on mouse hover rather than a mouse click. Any suggestions on how to do this in javafx8 and FXML .

Comment: what's wrong with opening the contextMenu on mouseEntered?

Comment: i'm able to capture the event but not sure how to show the menu items. `<MenuBar fx:id="menuBar" prefHeight="13.0" prefWidth="35.0"
  onMouseEntered="#showMenuItems">`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? Assuming that you have a Menu with id `menuFile`

```
        menuBar.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
        menuFile.show();
    });
```